# Triangle shifts by 1 each time

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testpyramid {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // TODO code application logic here
      int i = 0, j = 0, g = 0, n = 0;
      while (i >= 0) {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter an odd number:");
         i = input.nextInt();
         if ((i % 2) == 0) {
            System.out.println("Number not valid, please enter an odd number: ");
         } else {
            if ((i % 1) == 0) {
               for (; i > 0; i--) {
                  for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                     System.out.print(" ");
                  }
                  for (int k = i; k > 0; k--) {
                     System.out.print("* ");
                  }
                  System.out.println();
                  n++;
               }
            }
            System.out.println("Enter 1 to restart or 2 to exit:");
            g = input.nextInt();
            if ((g > 1) && (g < 3)) {
               break;
            } else {
               if ((g < 1) || (g > 3)) {
                  System.out.println("Must enter 1 or 2");
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

At the end of the input I made it ask if the user wants to try again. When I input the number again the output shifts the triangle to the right for some reason. I have been working on this project all day and out of all things this is what stumped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset `n` to zero after you get the height of the triangle.

```
// ...
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter an odd number:");
i = input.nextInt();
n = 0;                                     // <- Here
// ...
```

Comment: Hahahaha, unbelievable, im embarassed at how easy the fix was, shows that I'm a little burnt out from a full day of coding. Thanks a lot and cheers!

Comment: Glad I could help, those bugs can be tough to squash when you're are running on empty.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reset the `n` value in the beggining of your `while` loop.

```
while (i >= 0) {
   n = 0; 
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm Embarrassed at how I never spotted it.